# Issue with JavaScript Array and Split

Tags: javascript, arrays, html, split

Please have a look at the below code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--
To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
and open the template in the editor.
-->
<html>
    <head>
        <title>TODO supply a title</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

        <script>

            function ttsSpeak(text)
            {

                var textArray = text.split(" ");
                var finalString="";

                for(var i=0;i<textArray.length;i++)
                {
                    finalString = finalString+textArray[i]+"+";
                }

                alert(finalString);
            }
        </script>

    </head>
    <body>
        <div><p id="text">In meteorology surface.
            </p></div>
        <div><button id="speak" onclick="ttsSpeak(document.getElementById('text').innerHTML);">Speak</button></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

In here, my expected output is,

```
In+meteorology+surface+
```

But instead, I got the below

[image]

What have I done wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the statement

> ```
> finalString = finalString+textArray[i]+"+";
> ```

you're adding the plus sign after *every* item in your `textArray`, even in the last iteration. You might use [`join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) instead.

---

The markup

> ```
> <p id="text">In meteorology surface.
>             </p>
> ```

does contain lots of whitespaces you don't want. Remove them by calling [`trim()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim) on the string before splitting it.

```
alert(text.trim().split(" ").join("+")+"+");
```

Answer (score 2):

The innerHTML contains all the whitespace (i.e. `"             "`) at the end - this is being split to empty strings ("") which are then joined at the end.

The general approach to splitting on white-space as such is to use `/\s+/` (split on as much white-space as possible), possibly preceded by a trim.

```javascript
"foo     ".split(" ")          // -> ["foo", "", "", "", "", ""]
"foo     ".split(/\s+/)        // -> ["foo", ""]
"foo     ".trim().split(/\s+/) // -> ["foo"]
```

Using `/\s+/` will also "fix" the newline issue implicitly.

(Also, see [`textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.textContent) as pointed out by Amadan.)

Answer (score 2):

To help you visualise the reason, if you replace all the spaces in your HTML with an underscore, your text paragraph looks like this:

```
<p id="text">In_meteorology_surface.
____________</p>
```

with a newline after your text, and a bunch of spaces after it on the second line.

You either want to trim the text before you split it, or you want to split on possibly multiple spaces.

Also, you probably don't want to use `innerHTML`, but `textContent`.

Answer (score 1):

As prompted above, there is additional white space.
In future, to avoid unnoticeable whitespace when using split, you can use the trim() function before split.

In your case:

```
text = text.trim();
var textArray = text.split(" ");
```

Answer (score 0):

Your textArray has elements with their value = " " , a space, because of(between `.` and `</p>`):

```
<p id="text">In meteorology surface.
            </p>
```

(if there `n` number of spaces, then your textArray will have `n/2` number of elements which their values are just a space; **if the `n` is even** and `(n/2 - 1)` number of elements which their values are just a space **if the `n` is odd**)

In php you can use array_filter() to remove these empty objects from the array.

In javascript you can do as follows:

```
function isSpace(element){
 if(element != " " || element != "") return element;
}
textArrayWithoutEmptyObjects = textArray.filter(isSpace));
```

Further Reading about array filter in javascript is [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

Answer (score 0):

In for loop,you can write this finalString = finalString+textArray[i]+"+"; and it will give your expected output.